# Sed replacing line with line from variable

Tags: bash, sed

I am new here and I have one issue I can´t figure out . I am trying to replace one line in *.txt file with almost same line but modified. I am still getting errors or output file is without the change. Can you please help me?

Script:

```
var1=`grep "keyS.log\" type=" /C/tst/tst.txt`
x="<\!--"
if echo "$var1" | grep -q "$x"; then
   echo "Already disabled";
else
 prefix='<!-- '
 sufix='-->'
 modified=`echo "${var1/[[:space:]]/}" | sed 's:^.\(.*\).$:\1:'`
 final="${prefix}${modified}${sufix}"
 echo "${final}"
 `sed -i 's/${var1}/${final}/g' /C/tst/tst.txt`
fi
```

Line I am trying to modify in the file is like this:

```
<category="keyS" priority="1" appender="/tmp/keyS.log"/>
```

and should be like this:

```
<!-- category="keyS" priority="1" appender="/tmp/keyS.log"/-->
```

There are more lines starting with category and there can be different path behind appender= so it is dynamic.

Error is like:
sed: 1: "/C/tst/tst.txt": undefined label 'st/tst.txt'

When I tried to use

```
cat /C/tst/tst.txt  |  sed 's/${var1}/${final}/g' >> /C/tst/tsttmp.txt
```

line is not changed in tsttmp.txt and I lost also line spacing so whole text is one line.

Thank you in advance for any help

Stanislav

Answer (score 2):

shell is for calling tools and manipulating files/processes, not for manipulating text. The standard UNIX general purpose text manipulation tool is awk. Translating your shell script into awk it's:

```
awk '
/keyS.log" type=/ {
    if ( /<!--/ ) {
        print "Already disabled" |"cat>&2"
    }
    else {
        sub(/</,"<!-- ")
        sub(/>/,"-->")
    }
}
1' /C/tst/tst.txt
```

Use `awk -i inplace 'script' file` with GNU awk or `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file` with other awks to overwrite the original file.

Note that the regexp from your script, `keyS.log" type=`, doesn't exist in the sample input you posted, `<category="keyS" priority="1" appender="/tmp/keyS.log"/>`, so you'll have to change that to something that does if your posted sample input is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question right, below is what you require:

```
sed 's/^<\(category=.*keyS.log.*\)>$/<!-- \1-->/' /C/tst/tst.txt
```

The sed pattern

- looks for line starting with `<` followed by `category`. This will ignore if already commented out since in that case `<` will not be followed by `category`.
- Pattern put within `()` will stored as `\1` (and so on). Here we look for `keyS.log`.
- In case above two match happens, the replacement part will add html-style comments.

**NOTE**: I have not used `-i` option of sed for inline replacement. You can use it once you are sure this works for you.